# Signed Fixed Point Struct Pack as a single byte

Tags: python, c++, pack, fixed-point

Folks,

I would like to pack a signed fixed point number(Q(I,F)) in python and unpack the binary file in C++.

Packed the binary file in Python as:

```
for i in range(0, 100)
   var[I]=6.375
packed = struct.pack('<f'*100, *var)
with open('data.bin', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(packed)
```

And read it in CPP as:

```
FILE* filePtr;
filePtr = fopen("data.bin", "rb");
fread(dataArray, sizeof(aByte), 100, filePtr);
```

1. The above code works for a 4Byte packing. If I want to pack a vector, for example a 6.375(0110.0110 in Q4.4 FP format), as a single byte what is the format for struct.pack()?
2. What if the FP format is not a multiple of 8, e.g Q7.7, how to pad to the nearest byte(2 Bytes in this case) and pack each vector?

Cheers!